# Combining all csv files from Github Repository Link and make it a one csv file

Tags: python, pandas, csv, github, data-analysis

I want to collect all `csv` files from the following Github Repository link below and want to make it a new `csv` file (for data cleaning purpose):

https://github.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/tree/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_daily_reports

So that my new `csv` file will contain data from all dates.

Using the following command, I will be able to load only 01-01-2021.csv.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import requests

df = pd.read_csv ('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_daily_reports/01-01-2021.csv')

df.head()
```

How to load all `csv` files at once?

Comment: Why don't you just load them one by one in order to combine them?

Comment: Do you want to download and load. Or directly load from the url?

Comment: @LakpaTamang I want to load csv files directly from the url.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt. I want to load csv files directly from the url. (want to make a dynamic code, so that it will works for new uploads as well). It's a repo of covid19 daily reports

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a short solution using `pandas`, `requests` and `BeautifulSoup` to filter all the csv links:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer

html = requests.get('https://github.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/tree/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_daily_reports')

dfs = []
for link in BeautifulSoup(html.text, parse_only=SoupStrainer('a')):
    if hasattr(link, 'href') and link['href'].endswith('.csv'):
        url = 'https://github.com'+link['href'].replace('/blob/', '/raw/')
        dfs.append(pd.read_csv(url))
df = pd.concat(dfs)
```

*NB. testing the code, this runs in ~12min and yields a 2300506 rows × 21 columns final dataframe. Ideally one should add a multi-threading to it to download several files in parallel (reasonably, not to get kicked by the server)*

Answer (score 1):

The link you have provided has the csv file names in the format month-day-year.csv. So i have made a loop to create a filename and load csv directly from the given URL. This should work unless the website has random naming convention of the csv files.

```
years = [2020, 2021]
months = [month for month in range(1, 13)]
days = [day for day in range(1, 31)]
URL = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID- 
19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_daily_reports'
all_files = []
for year in years:
    for month in months:
        month = str(month).zfill(2)
        for day in days:
            day = str(day).zfill(2)
            print(f"{month}-{day}-{year}.csv")
            df = pd.read_csv(URL + f"/{month}-{day}-{year}.csv")
            all_files.append(df)
        final_csv_file = pd.concat(all_files, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```

This is the snapshot of the output that i got from the above source code. But here, i have looped for only two elements 1,2 for both day and month, and year 2021. As long as the website has non-random naming convention, this should work.
[image]

Comment: Okay! This looks fine. Let me check!! But the code doesn't seem to be working for me!? Getting "HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found" error. Your imports?

Comment: As i said, this error represented that the file is not present in that URL. The filename are automatically created with the loop and the program looks for the same filename in the URL. Probably, some CSV files with certain filenames are missing in the URL. You can check the order of files in the URL and modify the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go! You can specify the start and end dates to get all the data from those dates in between them. This also checks if the url for that particular date is present or not, and only if it is a valid url, does it add it to the final data frame.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd


def is_leap_year(year):
    # checks if the current year is leap year

    """
        params:
            year - int
        
        returns:
            bool
    """

    if((year%4==0 and year%100!=0) or (year%400==0)):
        return True
    else:
        return False


def split_date(date_str):
    # Splits the date into month, day and year

    """
        params:
            date_str - str (mm-dd-yyyy)
        
        returns:
            month - int
            day - int
            year - int
    """

    month, day, year = list(int(x) for x in date_str.split("-")) # For US standards, for rest of the world feel free to swap month and day
    return month, day, year


def generate_dates(start_date, end_date):
    # This doesn't validate the dates and it is assumed that the start_date and end_dates both are valid dates with the end date > start_date
    # This generates all dates bw start date and end date and also takes into account leap year as well

    """
        params:
            start_date - str (mm-dd-yyyy)
            end_date - str (mm-dd-yyyy)
        
        returns:
            dates - list of strings of dates between start_date and end_date
    """

    dates = []
    start_month, start_day, start_year = split_date(start_date)
    end_month, end_day, end_year = split_date(end_date)
    
    year = start_year
    while(year<=end_year):
        month = start_month if(year==start_year) else 1
        max_month = end_month if(year==end_year) else 12
        while(month<=max_month):
            day = start_day if(year==start_year) else 1
            if(month==2):
                max_day = 29 if(is_leap_year(year)) else 28
            else:
                max_day = 31 if(start_month in [1,3,5,7,8,10,12]) else 30
            if(year==end_year and month==end_month):
                max_day = end_day
            while(day<=max_day):
                new_date = f"{month}-{day}-{year}"
                dates.append(new_date)
                day+=1
            month+=1
        year+=1

        return dates


def check_if_url_is_valid(url):
    # This checks if the url is valid through the python requests library, by making a GET request. if the url is present and valid then it returns status code in (200-300)

    """
        params:
            url - str
        
        returns:
            bool
    """

    r = requests.get(url)
    if(r.status_code in range(200,300)):
        return True
    else:
        return False
        

def to_df(base_url, start_date, end_date):
    # Takes all the generated dates, creates a url for each date through the base url and then tries to download it, else prints out an error message

    """
        params:
            base_url - str it should be of the format "https://github.com/{}.csv" where the {} will be used for string formatting and different dates will be put into it

            returns:
                final_df - pd.DataFrame 
    """

    files = []
    dates = generate_dates(start_date, end_date)
    for date in dates:
        url = base_url.format(date)
        valid_url = check_if_url_is_valid(url)
        if(valid_url):
            df = pd.read_csv(url)
            files.append(df)
        else:
            print(f"Could not download {date} data as it may be unavailable")
    final_df = pd.concat(files)
    print(f"\n Downloaded {len(files)} files!\n")
    return final_df
```

UPDATE:

Here's the Google Colab link for the same - https://colab.research.google.com/drive/19ysmJ2wWaiEpzGae7XqOSPa-FfNZqza3?usp=sharing

Comment: I just got to know that python datetime library can generate dates bw start_date and end_date, so you could significantly reduce the total code size by using that

Comment: Then why don't you update your answer with this? ;)

Answer (score 0):

check out [pd.concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html)?

Assume that you have all file links:

```py
dfs = []
for l in links:
    df = pd.read_csv(l)
    dfs.append(df)
final_df = pd.concat(dfs)
```

Comment: Actually, the main issue is to load the filenames ending with .csv from the url ( not any local drive). Not working for me.